# Как правильно поставить ударение?

Tags: языкознание

Был такой политический деятель Фердинанд Лассаль. В фамилии Лассаль в именительном падеже ударение ставится на вторую букву "а". А как правильно поставить ударение в родительном падеже (Лассаля)? На вторую "а" или на "я"?

Answer (score 3):

В именах собственных, как правило, смещающихся ударений не бывает. Поэтому, Ласс**а**ля, Ласс**а**лю, о Ласс**а**ле и т. д., но, лассаль**я**нцы, лассаль**я**нский.